# Is there a way to "resource" by bash_profile without restarting terminal?

Tags: bash

I often times have to make changes to my `~/.bash_profile`, and I have to restart terminal for the changes to propagate. Is there any command I can run to re-source my `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: something like  `$ source ~/.bash_profile` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can just run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Or:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

This will reload/re-source the `.bash_profile` in the current shell.

I put this command in my `~/.bash_profile` for convenience:

```
alias reprofile='source ~/.bash_profile'
```

Then I just type `reprofile` or `repro` <kbd>TAB</kbd>.